# Android Alignment

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-framelayout

I have android layout issue

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"  android:layout_marginTop="670dp"  android:layout_width="1000dp"  android:layout_height="707dp" android:id="@+id/home"  android:background="@color/black"  >
     <ImageView    android:layout_width="1000dp"  android:layout_height="707dp"  android:background="@color/brown"                  android:id="@+id/graphic"      android:src="@drawable/anatomy_hooves"    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
     <TouchPanel   android:layout_width="1000dp"  android:layout_height="707dp"  android:background="@android:color/transparent"    android:id="@+id/touchLayer"   />
     <PenPanel     android:layout_width="1000dp"  android:layout_height="707dp"  android:background="@android:color/transparent"    android:id="@+id/penLayer"     />
</FrameLayout>
```

The TouchPanel and PenPanel  View which implement OnTouchListener  so I cane draw lines or draw with the finger

The ImageView has a selectable Image background, that you can then draw on top of
When I save the Image I use the following

```
home.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(home.getDrawingCache());
Log.i("VISIT","Bitmap    " + bmp.getWidth() + " x " + bmp.getHeight() + "      " + bmp.getDensity()  );
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Images/" + skeletonFileName);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    Log.i("VISIT","saved Skeleton to   ["+ skeletonFileName +"] ");
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("VISIT","Could Not save Skeleton to   ["+ skeletonFileName +"] ");
}
home.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Where home is the FrameLayout
The resulting PNG  has the ImageView Image, yet the drawn lines from TouchPanel and the finger painting from PenPanel
Are not to the same scale and are off center  in the PNG
but NOT on the screen.

Why?  What am I missing ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Anybody got any advice here, please ?